# No Module Name index

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6

Hi I'm new to python and also to pyflann. I did install pyflann and tried to run the test example of it. After executing, I'm getting an error

```
from pyflann import FLANN
import numpy as np

dataset = np.array(
     [[1., 1, 1, 2, 3],
     [10, 10, 10, 3, 2],
     [100, 100, 2, 30, 1]
     ])
testset = np.array(
     [[1., 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [90, 90, 10, 10, 1]
     ])
flann = FLANN()
result, dists = flann.nn(dataset, testset, 2, 
algorithm="kmeans"branching=32, iterations=7, checks=16)
print (result)
print (dists)

dataset = np.random.rand(10000, 128)
testset = np.random.rand(1000, 128)
flann = FLANN()
result, dists = flann.nn(dataset, testset, 5, algorithm="kmeans", 
branching=32, iterations=7, checks=16)
print (result)
print (dists)
```

When I try to execute the above code, I get something like this

```
from index import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'index'
```

Can somebody ans this as I've those files in my site-packages of pyflann and my python version is 3.6. And how should i proceed to run the above code.

Comment: Where are you using the index module in the above code, and what is the index module supposed to do? Is index a module within the package FLANN? In that case you need to do `from FLANN.index import *`

Comment: It's in __init__.py of pyflann package

Comment: Then you need to do a relative import from pyflann

Comment: OH, I understand. I just installed pyflann on python3.6 and I get the same thing: 

`>>> import pyflann 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kvnp/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyflann/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from index import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'index'
`

Comment: Could you suggest me the link for relative import?

Comment: Yes, How to solve this issue?

Comment: This got too deep for me. Try reading [here](https://github.com/primetang/pyflann/issues/1)? Good luck !

Comment: I can tell you that your bug is from the first line: `import pyflann` will kick it, so you can really cut this question down.

Comment: i fixed it by applying thorugh this link. There are changes in this library. also some methods are from python 2.7. Not compatible with python 3.6.

Comment: @kevinkayaks The link :- Link :- https://github.com/primetang/pyflann/pull/7 . Click on the below issues

Comment: lib\site-packages\pyflann\index.py", line 122, in nn
    pointer(self.__flann_parameters))

ArgumentError: argument 9: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_FLANNParameters instance instead of LP_FLANNParameters

Comment: You could edit the question to show `import pyflann` and its traceback, make the title 'pyflann python3.6 incompatability issue', then post your own answer. It might help someone sometime

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this:
https://github.com/primetang/pyflann/issues/1

Apparently, there are some syntax errors when you install pyflann for python3 which you need to fix. For instance:

- `except Exception,e` should be changed to `except Exception as e`.
- `from foo import *` should be changed to `from .foo import *`
- `exec` needs parentheses.
- in pyflann/io/datasets.py you need to write `from . import binary_dataset`, 
  `from . import dat_dataset`, `from . import npy_dataset`, and `from . import hdf5_dataset` instead of `import dat_dataset` and others.